# Como transformar elementos que virão depois de um argumento de função em string

Tags: python, discord.py

Esto fazendo uma integração da API do Discord com a do Gmail

Como posso fazer para o que vier depois do argumento "content" seja impresso?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaSxC.png

```
 @client.command()
 async def enviar_email(ctx, subject, to, content):
     
 #Create of E-mail
 msg = EmailMessage()
 msg['Subject'] = subject #Subject of E-mail
 msg['To'] = to #To whom will you send
 msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS #The email address you will use. You already changed it at the beginning of the code, don't mess with anything here.
 content = content
 msg.set_content(content) #Content of E-mail

 with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
     smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
     smtp.send_message(msg)
     await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, entreguei seu e-mail. \n \n Destinatário: {to} \n Assunto: {subject} \n Conteúdo: {content}')
     print(content)
```

Comment: Por favor, seria muito interessante você descrever a finalidade do projeto ate onde quer chegar , o que vc tentou realizar ( quais códigos usou ) de forma mais detalhada. Infelizmente não tem como ajudar com a sua atual postagem.

Comment: Eu quero enviar emails pelo chat do discord. Se você ver na imagem do post, somente a primeira palavra do conteúdo do email é enviada. Como faço para imprimir o que vier depois do argumento "content" na função enviar_email?

Comment: atualiza a sua postagem com a descrição rsss e inclui a imagem como anexo nao texto por favor

Comment: *...Como posso fazer para o que vier depois do argumento "content" seja impresso?..* não faz sentido. Vi que no histórico de edições que a pergunta esteve em língua inglesa. Caso ainda não tem domínio da língua portuguesa, como poderemos o ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Então, pelo que entendi, você quer que o seu bot no discord mostre o conteúdo da mensagem por inteiro que seria "Testando o teste", porém, ao pedir que o bot mande a resposta, você recebe apenas "Testando"

Pra resolver isso é bem simples, basta "compactar" o conteúdo da mensagem e para fazermos essa "compactação" usamos o * antes do "content". Seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
@client.command()
async def enviar_email(ctx, subject, to, *, content):
    #Create of E-mail
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = subject #Subject of E-mail
    msg['To'] = to #To whom will you send
    msg['From'] = EMAIL_ADDRESS #The email address you will use. You already changed it at the beginning of the code, don't mess with anything here.
    content = content
    msg.set_content(content) #Content of E-mail

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(EMAIL_ADDRESS, EMAIL_PASSWORD)
        smtp.send_message(msg)
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, entreguei seu e-mail. \n \n Destinatário: {to} \n Assunto: {subject} \n Conteúdo: {content}')
        print(content)
```